# Why memory keyword is mentioned in view function in solidity

Tags: memory, view, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
  function getAllWaves() public view returns (Wave[] memory) {
        return waves;
    }
```

I was going through _buildspace tutorial and found this code. I had previously read that memeroy keyword is used in solidity to specify that variable should be stored in memeroy(instead of state), so that we can destroy it after function call. But why memory is mentioned in return part of this view function since it just returns a value.

I am newbie in solidity so any articles relating to this also will help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All reference type variables (including an array) need to have their [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#data-location) specified.

The EVM is not able to return directly from storage, as the `storage` location modifier acts like a pointer, and it would be useless to return just a pointer instead of the actual value.

So it loads the value of `waves` array from storage to memory, and then returns it from memory.

Comment: So we should mention memory for all reference type return in solidity functions?

Comment: @KarthikPn In the absolute most cases - yes... There might be an edge case, where you'd accept some `calldata` value, perform a validation in the function, revert the transaction if the validation fails, and then return the very same `calldata` value, possibly along with some other value as another return param. But from the top of my head, I can't find a practical use case of this approach right now... So even though it's technically possible to return `calldata` as well, you'll most likely only ever return `memory` for a reference type (and never `storage`).